# How to capture HDR framebuffer in Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, framebuffer, hdr

I use the following code to read the standard 8-bit framebuffer, however I need to read the 10-bit HDR framebuffer that's used for HDR content on my HDR monitor.

As far as I can tell, `BI_RGB` is the only relevant enum option. Here's what I have so far, which works for 8-bit channels:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <fstream>

void capture_screen() {
 int nScreenWidth = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);
 int nScreenHeight = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);

 HWND hDesktopWnd = GetDesktopWindow();
 HDC hDesktopDC = GetDC(NULL);
 HDC hCaptureDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hDesktopDC);

 HBITMAP hCaptureBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hDesktopDC, nScreenWidth, nScreenHeight);
 SelectObject(hCaptureDC, hCaptureBitmap);

 BitBlt(hCaptureDC, 0, 0, nScreenWidth, nScreenHeight, hDesktopDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY | CAPTUREBLT);

 BITMAPINFO bmi = { 0 };

 bmi.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(bmi.bmiHeader);
 bmi.bmiHeader.biWidth = nScreenWidth;
 bmi.bmiHeader.biHeight = nScreenHeight;

 bmi.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
 bmi.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 32;
 bmi.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;

 auto* pPixels = new RGBQUAD[nScreenWidth * nScreenHeight];

 GetDIBits(hCaptureDC, hCaptureBitmap, 0,nScreenHeight, pPixels, &bmi, DIB_RGB_COLORS);

 //...               
 delete[] pPixels;

 ReleaseDC(hDesktopWnd, hDesktopDC);
 DeleteDC(hCaptureDC);
 DeleteObject(hCaptureBitmap);
}
```

Comment: With Win 8 and higher you'd better use Desktop Duplication API for capturing the desktop

Answer (score 1):

`Direct3D` has added HDR-related features to recent API updates, which use a new interface with the last digits. To access them, you must first query their underlying objects.

Example:

```
IDXGIOutput* output = /* initialize output */;
IDXGIOutput6* output6;
HRESULT hr = output->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IDXGIOutput6), (void**)&output6);
if(SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
    // Use output6...
    output6->Release();
} else {
    // Error!
}
```

You will be able to successfully compile this code only if you have sufficiently new version of Windows SDK installed. The code will execute successfully (as opposed to failing with an error code) only if the user has sufficiently new version of Windows 10.

You can then query for monitor capabilities by calling function [IDXGIOutput6::GetDesc1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/dxgi1_6/nf-dxgi1_6-idxgioutput6-getdesc1). You get structure [DXGI_OUTPUT_DESC1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/dxgi1_6/ns-dxgi1_6-dxgi_output_desc1) filled, which describes available color space, bits per component, red/green/blue primaries, white point, and the range of luminances available on the device.

Comment: Thanks! A few things: First, how should I initialize `IDXGIOutput`? (I'm fairly new to C++). Also, is it possible to get specific pixel values using this?

Comment: @RichardRobinson I am sorry to reply to you now. Since you are a novice in this field, I have provided you with some examples. https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/D2DAdvancedColorImages

Comment: is it even possible to get the rgb components of each pixel using this method?

Comment: @RichardRobinson I haven't tried to use `DirectX` to get specific pixel values of HDR, but according to the current data, `DirectX` is more about rendering colors. You can refer to the official document of [directx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3ddxgi/high-dynamic-range-and-wide-color-gamut), which shows how to get [metadata](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dxgi1_5/ns-dxgi1_5-dxgi_hdr_metadata_hdr10) structure.